# Post message to specific network in Yammer using the Yammer Javascript API

Tags: yammer

I am trying to post a message to another network in Yammer using the REST api. To the main company that I log into I have successfully read and posted a message to a specific group however I can read from a group in another network but not post.
Note when I read a post from another network I simply add the company name to the posted URL 
eg.

```
function GetMessages()
{
    yam.request.setAuthenticator('oauth2');
    yam.request.getAuthenticator({ auth: 'oauth2' }).setAuthToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    var access_token = "";     

   yam.request(
   {
        url: "https://api.yammer.com/childCompanyName/api/v1/messages/in_group/4787320.json",                        method: "GET",
    success: function (results)
    {             

       alert("The request was successful.");

       return results;
     }
}
```

This works fine reading messages however if I try to post a message using a similar ideology of using the company name in the posted url it doesn't work. I read in a similar post that your required to get the child companies bearer token and pass it through in the posted header. Here is the posted code I use....

```
function PostMessage()
{
      yam.request.setAuthenticator('oauth2');
      yam.request.getAuthenticator({ auth: 'oauth2' }).setAuthToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      var access_token = "";     
      yam.request(
                {

        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json",

        method: "GET",

        success: function(msg) 
                    {

            var access_token = "";

            for (var i=0; i < msg.length; i++) 
                            {

                //GRAB THE TOKEN FOR THE DESIRED NETWORK

                if (msg[i].network_permalink == "myChildCompany")

                {

                    access_token = msg[i].token;  //this works

                    break;

                }

            }
                     yam.request({ 
                           url: "https://www.yammer.com/myChildCompany/api/v1/messages.json",
                           method: "POST",
                            beforeSend: function (req)
                               {   
                                    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                              },
           data: { "body" : "123", "group_id":"4762174"} // Pass ur Group ID here
               });
             }
```

I have tried this with and without the "myChildCompany" in the URL however nothing seems to work. I check the response and it returns an Error: 401 Unauthorized.  I have no problems posting to the parent company.

Anyone had any experience with this and can maybe point me in the right direction?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question... Now I think about it what I was doing was a little silly. All I needed to do was set the auth token with myChildCompany's token using the yammer api instead of trying to set the token in the request header manually. Also don't use the child company's url to the yammer api as I tried in my previous attempt.

Here is the corrected code for anyone else that needs to post messages to a group outside the main company in Yammer using Javascript.

```
function PostMessage()
 {
      yam.request.setAuthenticator('oauth2');
      yam.request.getAuthenticator({ auth: 'oauth2' }).setAuthToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      var access_token = "";     
      yam.request(
      {
         url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/oauth/tokens.json",
         method: "GET",
         success: function(msg) 
         {
            var access_token = "";
            for (var i=0; i < msg.length; i++) 
            {
                //GRAB THE TOKEN FOR THE DESIRED NETWORK
                if (msg[i].network_permalink == "myChildCompany")
               {
                  access_token = msg[i].token;  //this works
                  break;
               }
             }
              yam.request.getAuthenticator({ auth: 'oauth2' }).setAuthToken(access_token);
             yam.request(
             { 
                 url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
                 method: "POST",
                 data: { "body" : "123", "group_id":"4762174"} // Pass "myChildCompany's Group ID here
             });
          }
       });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry just one more thing I thought I might add just as an aside... 
all URL links should be https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/ instead of www.yammer.com/api/v1/ otherwise you end up with the "no-same-origin" error in Chrome. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Could you confirm that the node yam.request is no longer present in the current API implementation?